# How to reset my PATH after breaking it accidentally?

Tags: fish

I think I run something incorrectly trying to add a directory to `PATH` in [fish](https://fishshell.com). Perhaps it was this:

```
set -g PATH my_foobar_directory "$PATH"
```

From [fish tutorial](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#path) I now understand that I shouldn't have added the double-quotes.
Better yet, should've used `fish_add_path my_foobar_directory`.

Lesson learned; however, the change has persisted somewhere, and nothing I try seems to recover the previous state. I also cannot find the previous `PATH` value — the console logs with it were washed away by copious `fish: Unknown command: python` etc, from `fish_prompt` bells & whistles.

Falling back to `bash` gives me bogus PATH as well — even after `set -e PATH`.

What do? How do I start over?

Comment: This looks like really good information, but it also looks off-topic to me since it isn't a question about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems" (i.e. programming).*  Would you consider reposting the question (and your solution, which was a good one) over on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)?  This one may get Roomba'd.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds disagreed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fish . [`software tools commonly used by programmers`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which `fish` definitely is.

Comment: just relaunch your shell. Path is read from bashrc and .profile when you open a terminal. In this case open bash and not fish. Read the path from $PATH and set it in fish if you wish.

Comment: @ulidtko Per the mods, shell usage questions must be directly programming related, or they are off-topic (just had a chat with one yesterday on this subject).  You cut off part of the "on-topic" guidance -- *"software tools commonly used by programmers; **and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**"* (not or).  Also, you'll notice a number of those questions tagged fish are either closed or *are* about programming.  And yes, some slip through the curation.

Comment: @TheFool I didn't mention that, as it's an obvious measure to take. It was not effective — universal variables are persisted and shared across fish sessions. @NotTheDr01ds are you saying that `PATH` issues are not unique to software development? I don't get it. Anyway, I don't care neither, the problem is solved for me at this point; and disputing mistaken (IMO) closing of a useful-to-many-others question isn't something I want to pay much effort to.

Comment: what stops you from reading the path from a non fish shell such as bash and copying it to your clipboard and then setting it in fish?

Comment: As mentioned in next-to-last paragraph. It didn't work.

Comment: what does it did not work mean? If you run the same command with a different argument last, shouldnt the result be the same except for the path now being different globally across all fish sessions?

Comment: I guess you open bash from fish in that case. Maybe set the default shell to bash for a second and logout and login again.

Comment: Note: If using `"$PATH"` with the quotes here breaks your shell, that points to you using a rather old version of fish. In fish >= 3.0 (released in December 2018), this would work. So you should probably upgrade. You will most likely find a package or repository at https://fishshell.com/.

Comment: Also I'm quite unhappy with how many fish questions are closed, especially because the policy is enforced rather inconsistently. Where would one go to close the entire tag here? I don't feel it's a good fit.

Comment: @faho That's unlikely to happen since there *are* certainly fish questions that are on-topic here, primarily around scripting.  But yes, most fish questions in the Stack Exchange network would be better suited for [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).  I also find some on [Super User](https://superuser.com) and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), of course, and that's fine as well.  I'm sure there are others, too.  Of course, there's also [r/fishshell](https://www.reddit.com/r/fishshell/), but I'm not a fan of the fact that you can't add updates there 6 months after a question.

Comment: And @ulidtko And no, `PATH` issues are certainly not unique to software development.  The path is clearly a "general computing/usage" topic, since it's how all programs on most OS's are found when not using a fully qualified path.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds The problem is that it's essentially impossible for a user to figure out beforehand if it is on-topic or not - not even by looking at the open questions, because it's enforced inconsistently!

Comment: @faho Let's continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239666)

Comment: Thanks @faho, your response appreciated. I've got `fish, version 3.3.1`.

Comment: @ulidtko Then you appear to have misidentified the cause of the issue.

Comment: Could be. Not really sure what exactly it was caused by; apparently I set the universal variable with a bogus value somehow.

Answer (score 1):

So for myself, I solved it like this.

In the process tree, I found a sufficiently long-running process. In my case, `cinnamon-session` worked — though any not-so-distant `fish` parent would do.

The idea being that in that process's environment, the previous PATH value could still be intact. It was.

Then basically — let's say the pid was 661 — print environment of pid 661 in fish format:

```
/bin/tr \0 ' ' < /proc/661/environ
# copy output
```

Then just pick that output, and feed it into the "universal" variant (fish-specific) of the PATH variable, taking care to erase all other variants:

```
set -e PATH
set -eg PATH
set -Ux PATH <paste>
```